# Is YouTube Data API v2 no longer supported?

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, saas, quota

I've been looking into getting a developer key for YouTube Data API v2.Navigating to the [page](https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard) Google lists for this purpose gives me a blank page--so there is no way to actually get a developer key. Does this page show up blank for anyone else?

Is this a sign from Google that it's time to move to version 3? I would really prefer not to, since it has some anti-features that I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There were some transient issues with https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html that should be resolved.

To answer the larger question, using the Data API v2 is still an option, but we're definitely recommending the Data API v3 for new development. (There are still a few pieces of functionality that are only available in v2, but that list is not very long.)

I'm not sure what "anti-features" you're referring to, so it's hard to comment beyond that.

Comment: is there any way to get YouTube Data API v2 developer key?